# what is bashrc and why do I need to put dot infront of some executable in order to execute it?

Tags: files, bashrc

1. what is bashrc
2. I know files/folders with dot meaning they are hidden, but why do I need to put dot to execute the green files
3. Coming from MS Dos, Linux seems to be very difficult to learn, where can I access USB drives, CD Roms and such?

Comment: Please don't combine multiple questions in a single post.Break this into separate questions.

Comment: @user97662 : for information on `bashrc` , see :http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work & http://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file

Comment: I have answered your first question. Please ask your other questions seperately so that others can find them and I'll be happy to answer those as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 -  bashrc:

This is like an autoexec.bat file.  It executes when you log into linux.  If you can write an autoexec.bat file (msdos), you can write a bashrc.  Anything you do with a msdos batch file can very easily be done with a linux script file.  However the reverse isn't valid.

Just because you can write very complex script files in Linux, doesn't mean you have to.

2 -  I don't know what you mean about a green file.  You don't need a dot to execute a file.  You can use a dot to load a new environment into the current session.  That might be kind of complex and something a novice might not have to do unless he has a specific reason for doing it.  Very few people in Windows work in a terminal screen.  Most of them do just about everything with a mouse gui click.   The same goes for Ubuntu also.

However, Linux has a plus in that just about anything you do in a gui can very easily be done at a command prompt.  This makes giving support to a novice very easy.  Instead of going through a lot of complex dialog telling a user what to click on and trying to guest how the next gui screen is going to appear, many users give a simple command line that can be copied and pasted and perform the function in one shot.

3 - Ubuntu has a navigation bar located on your right side.  Very near the top is something that looks like a file cabinet.  It's a file browser.  Plugging in your USB or CD Roms and such will appear in that file browser, with very easy access.

Even if you don't have the file browser on the screen, plugging in a new drive will most likely bring up the browser with the files.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I believe you'll be surprised at how easy the Ubuntu environment happens to be.

Are you saying you plugged in a USB drive and didn't get a popup showing you the content?

Comment: Do you mean the navigation bar (launcher) on the left hand side?

Answer (score 1):

1.) The bash man page is the authoritative reference:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.
>
> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.

The file is just shell commands. It is typically used to change prompts, set environment variables, and define shell procedures. Traditionally, the file `.profile` is used for this purpose, but bash has so many extensions that it needs its own startup file for users that want to put bashisms in startup files.

"Not a login shell" means things like script launches and usually terminal windows started by window managers. Sometimes I set up *nix systems to have `.bashrc` and `BASH_ENV` just source `.profile`. As long as you don't stray outside of POSIX shell commands then you will get the same initialization in any shell.

It's particularly valuable when sh is really bash, which sometimes happens. To do this use:

```
. .profile
```

One reason this is all so complex is because sometimes people put things that produce output into shell startup files, or they unconditionally set prompts. This causes lots of problems when running shell programs and backtick commands within languages, not to mention `system(3)` from C programs. The way bash starts up is designed, I think, to have one file where output and prompt setting is OK and one file where it isn't. Traditionally, a run-time test would be done to distinguish interactivity, for example, checking to see if the prompt is set.

source: https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file

Answer (score 0):

normally we suggest one question at a time..

.bashrc is a configuration file for your shell, bash.

http://linuxcommand.org/

Dot in front can mean a few things, post an examlpe.

- could specify current directory for programs not in your $PATH
- Could be source . file

Linux is different, not harder. With a poor attitude you will never learn. If you are not open to new things and learning, stay with your old OS

Comment: I should have flagged this. This really should be 3 questions.

Comment: well, i'd like to stay with DOS but nowadays you can hardly find any jobs that uses DOS.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'Green Files' you mean the default output of ls, they are green because they were marked executable. `chmod +x FileNameHere` the reason you need a dot to execute a file in your current directory is so it will execute that file, and not another file in your path with the same name.

bashrc is just a file that runs when you open a terminal to set up the environment for you. (path,local variables, aliases and functions)

your 'Green Files' are green because they are set up in bashrc to display that way.

[Linux Command Cheat Sheet](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/bash_cheat_sheet.pdf)

[Stanford Guide Basic Linux Commands](http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/basic-unix.html)